# Faster ways to extract stats by group from python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, aggregate

I am extracting some stats (sd, avg, max, first, last) using groupby from a python data frame but my function is relatively slow and would take many hours on my actual data. I am sure there are other faster ways than the method I am using on a very small sample data below. Please let me know about more efficient and better practices. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', 'A1', 15, 537],['A', 'A1', 16, 40],['A', 'A1', 17, 664],['A', 'A1', 18, 30],['A', 'A1', 19, 673],['A', 'A1', 20, 126],['A', 'A1', 21, 372],['A', 'A1', 22, 278],['A', 'A1', 23, 26],['A', 'A1', 24, 501],['A', 'A2', 12, 667],['A', 'A2', 13, 225],['A', 'A2', 14, 102],['A', 'A2', 15, 890],['A', 'A2', 16, 723],['A', 'A2', 17, 970],['B', 'B1', 8, 68],['B', 'B1', 9, 80],['B', 'B1', 10, 98],['B', 'B1', 11, 103],['B', 'B1', 12, 103],['B', 'B1', 13, 100],['B', 'B2', 21, 86],['B', 'B2', 22, 84],['B', 'B2', 23, 100],['B', 'B2', 24, 19],['B', 'B2', 25, 22],['B', 'B2', 26, 10],['B', 'B2', 27, 40],['B', 'B2', 28, 39],['B', 'B2', 29, 36],['B', 'B2', 30, 71],['B', 'B3', 50, 106],['B', 'B3', 51, 96],['B', 'B3', 52, 35],['B', 'B3', 53, 84],['B', 'B3', 54, 97],['B', 'B3', 55, 50],['B', 'B3', 56, 47]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Product', 'Model', 'DayId', 'Qty'])

def get_qty_stats(x, qty):    
# x already sorted by pt 
d = {}
d['sd_qty'] = x[qty].std()
d['avg_qty'] = x[qty].mean()
d['max_qty'] = x[qty].max()

open_rec = x.iloc[0] # 1st row
d['open_qty'] = open_rec[qty]

close_rec = x.iloc[-1] # last row
d['close_qty'] = close_rec[qty]

return pd.Series(d, index=['avg_qty', 'max_qty', 'sd_qty', 'open_qty', 'close_qty'])


%time
# call function to get stats for qty
df_out = df.groupby(['Product', 'Model']).apply(get_qty_stats, 'Qty').reset_index()
df_out.loc[df_out['sd_qty'].isna(), 'sd_qty'] = 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to get the data, it should be faster

```
grouper = ['Product', 'Model']
df.groupby(grouper).agg(avg_qty=('Qty', 'mean'),
                        max_qty=('Qty', 'max'), 
                        sd_qty=('Qty', 'std'), 
                        open_qty=('Qty', 'first'), 
                        close_qty=('Qty', 'last'))


                     avg_qty  max_qty      sd_qty  open_qty  close_qty
Product Model
A       A1     324.700000      673  261.111747       537        501
        A2     596.166667      970  354.727736       667        970
B       B1      92.000000      103   14.573949        68        100
        B2      50.700000      100   31.885385        86         71
        B3      73.571429      106   28.756780       106         47
```

Answer (score 1):

`.apply` is always a chokepoint (it's one of the slowest ways to perform operations on Pandas objects). Here, you can use `.agg` instead, and pass in the recognized string names for functions like `mean` instead of writing a custom single-use function:

```
%%timeit

df.groupby(['Product', 'Model']).agg({'Qty': ['mean', 'max', 'std', 'first', 'last']})

# 6.47 ms ± 520 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Compare:

```
%%timeit
df.groupby(['Product', 'Model']).apply(get_qty_stats, 'Qty').reset_index()

# 9.95 ms ± 55.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```